# equivalent option to "no-user-rc" for sshd_config?

Tags: ssh

Is there an option similar to **no-user-rc** that I can use in **sshd_config**?

I want to prevent from executing the **~/.ssh/rc** file for everybody (whether logging in using a password or key).

Using *Openssh 5.3p1*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If restricting everyone to using authorized keys only is not an option, you can use the ForceCommand directive in sshd_config to achieve what you want (Openssh 4.9 or later).  See [OpenSSH Security](http://www.openssh.org/security.html):

> OpenSSH 4.9 and newer do not execute
>   ~/.ssh/rc for sessions whose command
>   has been overridden with a
>   sshd_config(5) ForceCommand directive.
>   This was a documented, but unsafe
>   behaviour (described in OpenSSH 4.9
>   release notes).

The [patch notes](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-4.9) for OpenSSH 4.9 state the following regarding ForceCommand:

> Disable execution of ~/.ssh/rc for
>   sessions where a command has been
>   forced by the sshd_config ForceCommand
>   directive. Users who had write access
>   to this file could use it to execute
>   abritrary commands.  This behaviour
>   was documented, but was an unsafe
>   default and an extra hassle for
>   administrators.

One suggestion would be to use the solution proposed in this thread "[ForceCommand and ~/.ssh/rc](http://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/2008-March/026317.html)".